# Two array list c# loop through

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, c#-4.0, foreach

I have two array list c#. Below my code working for my requirement but it has lots of limitations. Can any one tell me how do I write below code efficient ways without value hard code? and support any number of "cname" values.  Because my below code has already value hardcoded. it support only 4(cname) values. more than 4 values come it say 'IndexOutOfRange'.

```
string couName1 ="";
string Colour = "";
var colors = new List<string>();
colors.Add("red");
colors.Add("green");
colors.Add("blue");
colors.Add("yellow");
var cname = new List<string>();
 cName.Add("AAAA");
 cName.Add("BBBB");
 cName.Add("CCCC");
 cName.Add("DDDD");

foreach (var couName in cname)
{
    couName1 = CouName.ToString();
}

foreach (var colors1 in colors)
{
    if ((colors1 == "red") && (couName1 == cname[0]))
    {
        Colour = colors1.ToString();
    }
    else if ((colors1 == "green") && (couName1 == cname[1]))
    {
        Colour = colors1.ToString();
    }
    else if ((colors1 == "blue") && (couName1 == cname[2]))
    {
        Colour = colors1.ToString();
    }
    else if ((colors1 == "yellow") && (couName1 == cname[3]))
    {
        Colour = colors1.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `cName` in `var cname = new List<string>(cName);`? What is output (the value of `cname`)? What is the point of the first loop - it sets `couName1` to the last value in `cname`. (I assume `CouName.ToString()` is a typo and it should be `couName.ToString()`) Nothing here makes sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hello MarcinJuraszek, my requirement is for example couName1 has 3 to 16 unique names. Database come string CouName = reader.GetString(9);. couName1 = AAAA, CouName name have AAAA has 10 records that 10 all data display on red colour. couName1 = BBBB, CouName name have BBBB has 20 records, display all BBBB 20 records display on yellow, etc....

Comment: Your not making any sense. You need to show more code and what the output is and what the expected result is. And if you want to respond to Marcin, add a comment to his answer!

Comment: So what do you want the result to be? Do you mean if the value is `AAAA` your want the color to be `red` and if its `BBBB` you want the color to be `green`? You need to explain what your trying to acheive

Comment: yes it is,  AAA=red, BBB=green, CCC=yellow etc......

Comment: out put value must be colour name only, because particular colour name loop through and Insert Database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this

```
            List<string> lst1 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ccc", "aaa" };

            List<string> lst2 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ddd", "ccc", "eee" };

            List<string> lst3 = new List<string>() { "Red", "yellow", "blue" };

            Dictionary<string, string> NameColor = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (string name1 in lst1)
            {
                foreach (string name2 in lst2)
                {
                    if (name1 == name2 && NameColor.Count < lst3.Count && !NameColor.ContainsKey(name1))
                    {
                        NameColor.Add(name2, lst3[NameColor.Count]);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Check this 1....

```
        List<string> lst1 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff" };

        List<string> lst2 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ddd","ccc","eee"  };

        List<string> lst3 = new List<string>() { "Red", "yellow", "blue" };

        Dictionary<string, string> NameColor = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (string name1 in lst1)
        {
            foreach (string name2 in lst2)
             {
                if (name1 == name2 && lst1.IndexOf(name1) < lst3.Count)
                {
                    NameColor.Add(name1, lst3[lst1.IndexOf(name1)]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello Exception error's (An item with the same key has already been added.) comes when I going add same name. The list1 names most of the time duplicate but List2 all names are unique.  lst1 = new List<string>() { "aaa","aaa", "aaa",  "ccc", "ddd","ccc","ccc", "eee", "fff" };

Comment: Hi Bob , R u still facing issue ? refer this

Comment: Yes It's , please check my comment's and my code (hard code values). If you can modify your code my requirement. thanks

Comment: if add your code that line Colour = colors1.ToString(); only insert last colour valve(my list1 has five names therefore all record colour purple)  if (CName == CouName && cname.IndexOf(CName) < colors.Count)
 {

  Colour = colors1.ToString();

   }

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

1. Get the index where `couName == cname[i]`:

   ```
   var index = cname.FindIndex(x => x == couName);
   ```
2. Set `Colour` to corresponding value from `colors1`:

   ```
   Colour = colors1[index];
   ```

You might want to incorporate some checks in between, to make sure your code doesn't break when value is not found.

Comment: Hello MarcinJuraszek, var index always 0, Can you please modify for me my code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi bob check foolowing snippet does it meet ur requirement...

```
public void ArrayDemo()
        {
            List<string> lst1 = new List<string>() { "Red", "Blue", "White" };

            List<string> lst2 = new List<string>() { "Red", "Black", "White" };

            foreach (string color1 in lst1)
            {
                foreach (string color2 in lst2)
                {
                    if (color1 == color2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(color1);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Final out put should be like this, Name1 = Red, Name2= Black,  Name3=White etc....

Comment: Bob, is that mean u have 3 lists... 2 for comparision and 3rd for assignment ?

Comment: Hello Vrishali, Can do for me only lst1 and lst2 for me, please check my edit code list1. thanks

Comment: List<string> lst1 = new List<string>() { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" };

Comment: Bob, How can we campare Name1 with color n ......
simply tell ur inputs and expected output

Comment: Hello Vrishali, I am compare any values I need assigned values, pls check my code and any loop or conditions okay for me.

Comment: sorry about that above comments, Hello Vrishali, I am not compare any values I need assigned values, pls check my code and any loop or conditions okay for me.

Comment: From where u need to assign that value will that be from database ?

Comment: Yes it is. Can you do for me this example for me. List<string> Name2 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "ccc", "ddd","eee","fff" };
List<string> Name1 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ddd","ccc","eee" };
List<string> colour = new List<string>() { "Red", "yellow", "blue" };
aaa==red, ccc==yellow, ddd==blue

Comment: DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));

            // Here we add five DataRows.
            table.Rows.Add("Red");
            table.Rows.Add("Blue");
            table.Rows.Add("White");
            table.Rows.Add("Green");

            List<string> lst3 = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow val in table.Rows)
            {
                lst3.Add(val.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            }

Comment: Simply loop on ur Datatable and assign vamues to list like above comment

Comment: Hello, follow only these 3 array list and modify your code that all List<string> Name2 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "ccc", "ddd","eee","fff" };
List<string> Name1 = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ddd","ccc","eee" };
List<string> colour = new List<string>() { "Red", "yellow", "blue" };
finally out put is aaa==red, ccc==yellow, ddd==blue

Comment: no need any Datata just think only 3 list of array. finally value should be display  aaa=red, ccc=yellow, ddd=blue